# Send a POST http request with XML content

Tags: c, xml, http, post

I like to send a http POST request and a XML content to my sensor :

For the counting data:

```
http://{SensorIP}:5211/1.0-PAI/PassengerCountingService/SubscribeAllData
```

The XML data:

```
<SubscribeRequest>
    <Client-IP-Address>
       <Value>{HostIP}</Value>
    </Client-IP-Address>
    <ReplyPort>
       <Value>{YourReplyPort}</Value>
     </ReplyPort>
     <ReplyPath>
          <Value>{YourReplyPath}</Value>
     </ReplyPath>
</SubscribeRequest>
```

I have a socket TCP for connecting to the sensor but i Don't khnow how sending this XML format with POST operation.

Have-you an idea ?
Edited:

```
 char buffer[1024] = "";
    int nOctetsRecus = 0;
    int nOctetsEnvoyes = 0;
    int tailleBuffer = 0;
    int boucle = 1;
    char * URL;
    char * xml_data;
    nOctetsRecus = 0;
    nOctetsEnvoyes = 0;
    tailleBuffer = 0;
    boucle = 1;

    //STEP1: Initialisation Winsock
    iwsaStartup = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &winSockData);
    if (iwsaStartup != 0)
    {
        printf("APICP: open_socket(): WSAStratup Failed\r\n");
    }
    //LOG_INFO("APICP: opensocket(): WSAStarup Success\r\n");

    //STEP3: Socket UDPSocketClient Creation
    UDPSocketClient = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (UDPSocketClient == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Socket creation failed with error: %d\r\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    printf("La socket %d est ouverte en TCP/IP.\n", UDPSocketClient);
    // on configure l'interface de connexion
    IRMAServer.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(Addr_TCP_IRMA); // adresse IP du serveur IRMA
    IRMAServer.sin_family = AF_INET;
    IRMAServer.sin_port = htons(Port_TCP_IRMA); // sin_port et sin_addr doivent être en Network Byte Order // htons() convertit
                                            //un entier court depuis l'ordre des octets de l'hôte vers celuidu réseau (host to network short)
    //printf("Connexion a %s sur le port %d\n", inet_ntoa(IRMAServer.sin_addr), htons(IRMAServer.sin_port));
    if(connect(UDPSocketClient, (SOCKADDR*)&IRMAServer, iIRMAServerLen) != SOCKET_ERROR) // si le client réussit à se connecter au serveur
        printf("Connexion a %s sur le port %d\n", inet_ntoa(IRMAServer.sin_addr), htons(IRMAServer.sin_port));
    else
        printf("Erreur de connexion.");

    // on reçoit les données envoyées par le serveur
    /*nOctetsRecus = recv(UDPSocketClient, buffer, 1024, 0);
    if(nOctetsRecus != SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("%d octets ont ete recus\n", nOctetsRecus);
        printf("texte recu : %s", buffer);
    }
    else
        printf("Les donnees n'ont pas ete recues");*/
    // le client envoie des données au serveur
    URL="/1.0-PAI/PassengerCountingService/SubscribeAllData";
    xml_data="<SubscribeRequest> <Client-IP-Address> <Value>192.168.X.X</Value> </Client-IP-Address> <ReplyPort></Value> </ReplyPort> <ReplyPath> <Value>C:\</Value> </ReplyPath> </SubscribeRequest>";
    tailleBuffer = sprintf(buffer, " POST %s HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:192.168.0.168:5211\r\nAccept:text/xml\r\nContent-Type:text-xml\r\nContent-Length:1024\r\n\r\n%s"
                          ,URL, xml_data);
    nOctetsEnvoyes = send(UDPSocketClient, buffer, tailleBuffer, 0);
    if(nOctetsEnvoyes != SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("%d octets envoyes au serveur\n", nOctetsEnvoyes);
        printf("texte envoye : %s", buffer);
    }
    else
        printf("Erreur : donnees non envoyees au serveur");

            // on reçoit les données envoyées par le serveur
    nOctetsRecus = recv(UDPSocketClient, buffer, 1024, 0);
    if(nOctetsRecus != SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("%d octets ont ete recus\n", nOctetsRecus);
        printf("texte recu : %s", buffer);
    }
    else
        printf("Les donnees n'ont pas ete recues");


    // on ferme la connexion
    closesocket(UDPSocketClient);
    WSACleanup(); // libère les ressources allouées par la fonction WSAStartup()

getchar();

return 0;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfKR4.png)

Have-you an idea why i have this ICMP message?

Comment: You can send **any** string, in server side you can parse in **any** operations.
Just add header `Content-Type: text/xml` for keep standards.
You know how to create http request raw?

Comment: Are you aware, how to do a GET?

Comment: @IgorGalczak : I do that :sprintf(buffer, "POST /1.0-PAI/PassengerCountingService/SubscribeAllData HTTP/1.0\r\n\ Host:10.3.79.167:5211\r\n Content-Type:text/xml\r\n <then the xml content>"); but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Just send this string by tcp socket by port 5211:

```
POST /1.0-PAI/PassengerCountingService/SubscribeAllData HTTP/1.1
Host: SensorIP
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0
Accept: */*
Content-Type: text-xml
Content-Length: {strlen(THIS)}

<SubscribeRequest>
    <Client-IP-Address>
       <Value>{HostIP}</Value>
    </Client-IP-Address>
    <ReplyPort>
       <Value>{YourReplyPort}</Value>
     </ReplyPort>
     <ReplyPath>
          <Value>{YourReplyPath}</Value>
     </ReplyPath>
</SubscribeRequest>
```

Between headers and content are one free line so: `\r\n\r\n`.
Remember about `Content-Length`.
Basic info about HTTP: https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/webprogramming/HTTP_Basics.html

Comment: why those lines : User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0
Accept: */*                                                                                                                           the sensor will send us a XML file also

Comment: User-Agent tell server about you device you can write there anythink but this is for sure in correct format. (Linux Firefox), I dont know your sensor require this header, you can remove this and check works.
So Accept can be `text/xml` not `*/*`.

Comment: So the request will be like this : POST /1.0-PAI/PassengerCountingService/SubscribeAllData HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.3.79.167
Accept: text/xml \r\n\r\n
Content-Type: text-xml
Content-Length: {strlen(THIS)}

<SubscribeRequest>
    <Client-IP-Address>
       <Value>{HostIP}</Value>
    </Client-IP-Address>
    <ReplyPort>
       <Value>{YourReplyPort}</Value>
     </ReplyPort>
     <ReplyPath>
          <Value>{YourReplyPath}</Value>
     </ReplyPath>
</SubscribeRequest>???

Comment: @emmy No, {strlen(THIS)} - replace with real sending string len (bytes). After every Header is NL (\r\n) so like this:
```
POST /1.0-PAI/PassengerCountingService/SubscribeAllData HTTP/1.1 \r\n
Host: 10.3.79.167 \r\n 
Accept: text/xml \r\n 
Content-Type: text-xml \r\n 
Content-Length: {strlen(THIS)} \r\n 
\r\n
<SubscribeRequest> <Client-IP-Address> <Value>{HostIP}</Value> </Client-IP-Address> <ReplyPort> <Value>{YourReplyPort}</Value> </ReplyPort> <ReplyPath> <Value>{YourReplyPath}</Value> </ReplyPath> </SubscribeRequest>
```

Comment: i do this :  URL="/1.0-PAI/PassengerCountingService/SubscribeAllData"
 xml_data="<SubscribeRequest> <Client-IP-Address> <Value>10.3.79.59</Value> </Client-IP-Address> <ReplyPort>9999</Value> </ReplyPort> <ReplyPath> <Value>/HD/API/</Value> </ReplyPath> </SubscribeRequest>"
    tailleBuffer = sprintf(buffer, " POST %s HTTP/1.1 \r\n Host: 10.3.79.167 \r\n Accept: text/xml \r\n Content-Type: text-xml \r\n Content-Length: 260 \r\n\r\n%s"
        ,URL, xml_data);

Comment: nOctetsEnvoyes = send(sock, buffer, tailleBuffer, 0);
    if(nOctetsEnvoyes != SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        LOG_INFO("%d octets envoyes au serveur\n", nOctetsEnvoyes);
        LOG_INFO("texte envoye : %s", buffer);
    }

Comment: When i send this request i have ICMP response Type 3: (Destination unreachable) and Code:3(Port unreachable). Have-you an idea please?